# Java generics compile error "Class<capture#1-of ? ..."

Tags: java, generics

I'm in trouble with using `javax.swing.event.EventListenerList` class in my personal Java project. It's not simple one, so I made a simple example that has same problem.

```
package test;
public class GenericTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericTest gt = new GenericTest();
        gt.doTest(String.class);
    }
    private void doTest(Class<? extends Comparable> type) {
        doSomething(type, "test"); // Compile error :
        // The method doSomething(Class<C>, C)
        // in the type GenericTest is not applicable for the arguments
        // (Class<capture#1-of ? extends Comparable>, String)
    }
    // third party API like javax.swing.event.EventListenerList.add()
    private <C extends Comparable> void doSomething(Class<C> ct, C c) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I got the generics compile error like that in the codes.

I have many classes extends a specific interface like `java.lang.Comparable` and I want to handle all of them with single method like `doTest()` in the codes.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Well your `doSomething` method wants the second parameter to be an instance of the class used for the first parameter. Imagine if I called `doTest(Integer.class)`...

Comment: Thanks. I got the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `c` in `doSomething` as `Comparable` or `String`:

```
    doTest(String.class);
}
private static void doTest(Class<? extends Comparable> type) {
    doSomething(type, "test"); 

}
// third party API like javax.swing.event.EventListenerList.add()
private static <C extends Comparable> void doSomething(Class<C> ct, Comparable c) {
    // ...
}
```

Please note that you cannot cast implicitly from `Object`,`String` or `Comparable` to `C`. To get more insight, inside the `doSomething` try to do this:

```
C s = c; //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Comparable to C
```